# Adjust tabulars inside minipages

Tags: tables, minipage

I want to place some tabulars in specific order using `colorbox` and `minipage`. This is the code I used:

```
\fcolorbox{white}{blue!20}{
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
        A & A \\
        A & A\\
        A & A\\
        \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\fcolorbox{white}{red!20}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
        B & B \\
        B & B\\
        \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}} %\vfill
\fcolorbox{white}{green!20}{
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
        C & C \\
        C & C\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}}\vfill
\end{minipage}
```

[image]

But as it is illustrated in the picture below, I fail to adjust the boxes on the top (see blue and red boxes, they should be top adjusted).

Any ideas on how to top, horizontally adjust the boxes would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try adding the optional argument `[t]` to each tabular?

Comment: @Bernard Yes, I just did. No luck there.

Comment: Then, as a workaround, you can add an empty row to the second  tabular, or simply colour the tabulars background  with `\columncolor{…}`.

Answer (score 2):

You can define invisible `\hrule` named `\hrulei` and you can put it to the places where you want to be vertically aligned:

```
\def\hrulei{\hrule height0pt\relax}

\hbox{%
\fcolorbox{white}{blue!20}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\hrulei
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
        A & A \\
        A & A\\
        A & A\\
        \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
}\kern2pt %<<< space between blue column and next column
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\fcolorbox{white}{red!20}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
\hrulei
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
        B & B \\
        B & B\\
        \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}} %\vfill
\fcolorbox{white}{green!20}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
        C & C \\
        C & C\\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{minipage}}\vfill
\end{minipage}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of minipages I would rather use `tabularx` table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \setlength\arrayrulewidth{4pt}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \arrayrulecolor{white}
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\linewidth}{X|X}
    \cellcolor{blue!30}
        \begin{tabular}{ll}
    A & A \\
    A & A\\
    A & A\\
        \end{tabular}   &   \cellcolor{red!30}
                            \begin{tabular}{ll}
                        B & B \\
                        B & B\\
                            \end{tabular}   \\  
    \hline
                        & \cellcolor{green!20}
                            \begin{tabular}{ll}
                        C & C \\
                        C & C\\
                            \end{tabular}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]